# Refresh Token Google Drive Api

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have the following code which gets access credential for my app and stores them in a file so that I do not need to login again. However, the access token is valid for 1 hour, how can I use the refresh token with the existing code to get valid credential without bothering the user to do it manually by signing in and allowing the app ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                         
import httplib2
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage

# Copy your credentials from the console                                                                                                  
CLIENT_ID = 'PASTE_YOUR_ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'PASTE_YOUR_SECRET'

# Check https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes for all available scopes                                                               
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

# Redirect URI for installed apps                                                                                                         
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# Create a credential storage object.  You pick the filename.
storage = Storage('a_credentials_file')

# Attempt to load existing credentials.  Null is returned if it fails.
credentials = storage.get()

# Only attempt to get new credentials if the load failed.
if not credentials:

    # Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials                                                                                 
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)

    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()

    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
    storage.put(credentials)


# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials                                                                    
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

# Use 'drive_service' for all of the API calls
```